# Character Reference Issue for Outlook

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

We are trying to access outlook email through EWS  via java code. For some of the email we are facing character reference issue.

Error message:

> ParseError at [row,col]:[852,6] Message: Character reference "&#

Code snippet:

```
try { 
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2); 
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials(EMAIL_ID, EMAIL_PWD); service.setCredentials(credentials); service.setUrl(new URI("https://*****************/ews/exchange.asmx")); service.setTraceEnabled(true); ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS = new            ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x007D,MapiPropertyType.String); PropertySet propset = new PropertySet(PropertySet.FirstClassProperties.getBasePropertySet(),ItemSchema.MimeContent,PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS); propset.setRequestedBodyType(BodyType.Text);
ItemView view = new ItemView(30);
view.getOrderBy().add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending);
FindItemsResults<Item> findResults;
findResults = service.findItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,"Body:"+currency, view);

if (findResults.getTotalCount() == 0) {
    logger.info("INFO:: There is eno emails available");
}
else {
    for (Item item : findResults) {
        EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(service, item.getId(), new               
        PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties, EmailMessageSchema.Attachments));
        EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.bind(service, item.getId(), propset);
        item.load();
        //emailBody = item.getBody().toString();
        emailBody = message.getBody().toString();
        logger.info("Email Body " + StringUtils.normalizeSpace(emailBody));
        Date dateTimeReceived = item.getDateTimeReceived();
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        Date todays_date = new Date();
        resultList.add(emailBody);
     }
  item.delete(DeleteMode.MoveToDeletedItems);
 }
}} catch (Exception e) {logger.info("Error in Executing outlookEmailRead : " +e.getMessage());}
```

POM dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.ews-java-api</groupId>
    <artifactId>ews-java-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I found it is a known issue from Microsoft https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/issues/353

But not able to fix the issue.

Comment: You are dealing with an Exchange server directly without involving Outlook.

Comment: As an aside don’t use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. They are troublesome and long outdated. Use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`. [Oracle Tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).